# Question about definition of matrix representation of linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V and W be finite-dimensional vector spaces with ordered bases $\beta={v_1,v_2,...,v_n}$ and $\gamma={w_1,w_2,...,w_m}$. Let $T:V \rightarrow$ be linear. Then for each j, $1 \leq j \leq n$, there exist unique scalars $a_{ij} \in F$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, such that $T(v_j)= \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}w_i$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$.

> Definition: using the notation above, call the m by n matrix A defined by $A_{ij}=a_{ij}$, the matrix representation of T in the ordered bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and write A=$[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$. If V=W and $\beta$=$\gamma$, then we write A=$[T]_\beta$

My question for A=$[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$, I know the superscript is the output while the subscript is the input. I want to know since in this case, A is a m by n matrix, is it always true that the input is always the number of columns of the matrix while the output is always the number of rows of the matrix A?

Comment: I prefer to write the input basis as the superscript and output as subscript, since we write $[v]_\beta$ for the coordinates of the vector $v$. That way, a superscript “cancels” against the subscript of the next factor to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the words input and output are confusing me, so I hope my answer makes sense to you.

The matrix $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ gives, when applied to *coordinate vectors* (i.e. tuples of scalars) with respect to the basis $\beta$, coordinate vectors with respect to the basis $\gamma$. These coordinate vectors give you vectors in $V$ and $W$ respectively by using the according linear combinations of the basis vectors. The beautiful result of linear algebra is that, up to conversion between coordinate vectors and 'proper vectors', matrices and linear transformations do exactly the same.

Of cause, to be able to be multiplied with coordinate vectors with respect to the basis $\beta$, $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ needs to have as many columns as $\beta$ has elements. Likewise it has to have as many rows as $\gamma$ has elements.

Comment: Sorry that was how my professor explains intuitively. Thanks and that's what i want to know about.

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help you :)